# Parse a HTML page

Tags: html, vb.net

So, I have a html page and, in one node of this HTML, i have one atribute called src and this attribute is a link... how I can get this link ?

What i mean:

```
<img border='0' id='image' src='/scripts/image/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?type=rca&amp;guid=82ca2bae-12b2-441b-b6fa-56c315c935ae'>
```

The attribute src is a link, how I can get the link of that ?
I get the src string, but, no the link... to get the src string, i maded this:

```
    If doc.Body.InnerHtml.Contains("image") Then
        MessageBox.Show(doc.GetElementById("image").GetAttribute("src"))
    End If
```

So, the '/scripts/image/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?type=rca&guid=82ca2bae-12b2-441b-b6fa-56c315c935ae' is a link...

['/scripts/image/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?type=rca&guid=82ca2bae-12b2-441b-b6fa-56c315c935ae'](http://www.google.com.br/%22getThisLink%22) <- like this, undersantd ? I jsut whant to get this link.... ( the hiperlink )

So, how I can get the link ?

Comment: How are you getting the HTML? What object is it stored in?

Comment: in doc... just see the object variable... "doc"

Comment: What _type_ is the variable? How did you populate it?

Comment: I have the intire html on doc variable, I just whant to get an link... the attribute src represent a link... ( hiper link )

Comment: Is this a job for the HTML Agility Pack? http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: But what **is** `doc`? An `XmlDocument`? An `XDocument`? A `WebControl`? Something else? How do you load the HTML into it?

Comment: I have chenged my quetion, see the question...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementsById('elementID').src
```

Please check [test.html](http://www.eslamifar.com/download/stackoverflow/15032411/test.html)

Answer (score -1):

If you're using jQuery, you could use **.attr()** and **.text()** to grab the src of the image and output the result as text to a div (or whatever). See this jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wWpT9/

HTML:

```
<img src="path-to-your-image/photo.jpg" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
var src = $("img").attr("src");
$("#result").text(src);
```

Answer (score -2):

if i understand your question correctly that you want to get the src value of your image tag is it ?? then you can use jquery for that like this

```
var i = $('#image').attr('src');
```

Comment: the src conttent is a hipperlink... I just whant to get the link of content

Comment: This is how you would do in using jQuery in the client, yes. The code, however, suggests this is to be done server side using VB.NET